# I receive an alert that containts more fields than the content type at which the Word document is associated to. Why?

Tags: alert, content

I receive an alert which contains more fields than the content type that the Word Document is associated with.

In other word, the alert contains many fields that I don't need and that they are not included in the content type used for the Word document. Can we decide which fields will be in the alert or which content type ?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your content type where you will see list of all fields/column. For each column you don't want to see, set that to hidden. It will not show up in forms or in document properties.

**Library Settings** > under **Content Type** section, click on the content type (e.g.: Document) to see the columns and hide them.

If the **Content Type** section is not visible, make sure **Allow management of content type** is set to Yes in **Library Settings** > **Advanced Settings**.

HTH